# Contour line labels on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, maps, label, leaflet, contour

I have a [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map with a geoJSON containing contour lines. The elevation corresponding to each line is located in feature.properties.Elevation of the geoJSON. I want to achieve the following:

[image: Contour lines map]

What I've tried to achieve this in leaflet is to calculate the center of each polyline and then add a marker to that position containing the data from feature.properties.Elevation.

```
L.geoJson(contourJSON, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var label = L.marker(layer.getBounds().getCenter(), {
      icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'label',
        html: feature.properties.Elevation,
        iconSize: [100, 40]
      })
    }).addTo(map);
  }
});
```

Which kind of works, but does not have a nice styling and it's not really clear which value belongs to a specific line:

[image: Contour lines output]

What would be a better method of adding the elevation labels in such a way that it is readable and maybe dynamic to the current zoom level? I'm using Leaflet 1.0.3 so maybe [Tooltip](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tooltip) could offer a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in those Leaflet plugins, possibly combined: (not sure how easy it would be to combine them)

- [Leaflet.LabelTextCollision](https://github.com/yakitoritabetai/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision) ([demo](https://yakitoritabetai.github.io/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision/))

> …display[s] labels on vector data while avoiding label collisions.

- [Leaflet.TextPath](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath) ([demo](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.TextPath/))

> Shows a text along a Polyline.

You might also want to check out the rest of [Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html).

BTW, I am not sure placing your label / marker at the polyline "center" is appropriate. You might just pick one of its vertices, or for example the farthest to the right / East to have an effect similar to the example you provide.